# can we call python script in node js and run node js to get call?

Tags: android, python, node.js

```js
python.py

from pymongo import MongoClient
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

host = "10.0.0.10"
port = 8085

@app.route('/name/<string:name>',methods=['GET','POST'])
def GetNoteText(name):
    
    print name
    
    return "Data Received"

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def abc():
    print "Hii"
    return ('Welcome')

users=[]   
@app.route('/getNames')
def getName():
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
    db = client.bridgeUserInformationTable
    cursor = db.bridgeUsersInfo.find()
    for document in cursor:
        #print "Name : ",document['name']
        users.append(document['name'])
        print document['name']
    #print (users)
    return "<html><body><h1>"+str(users)+"</h1></body></html>"
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
        host=host, port=port
        )
```

```js
node.j

var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
 
PythonShell.run('pass.py', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});
```

As i tried can we call python script in node js after running node js script from getting input from the android device? I am lit bit confused how it should be solved? And how both languages should communicate each other like python to node js?

Answer (score 1):

yes, we can call python file from node js you may use cmd-node package for this purpose.

```
const cmd=require('node-cmd');
 
const processRef=cmd.run('python -i');
let data_line = '';
 
//listen to the python terminal output
processRef.stdout.on(
  'data',
  function(data) {
    data_line += data;
    if (data_line[data_line.length-1] == '\n') {
      console.log(data_line);
    }
  }
);
 
const pythonTerminalInput=`primes = [2, 3, 5, 7]
for prime in primes:
    print(prime)
 
`;
 
//show what we are doing
console.log(`>>>${pythonTerminalInput}`);
 
//send it to the open python terminal
processRef.stdin.write(pythonTerminalInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

[ZERORPC](http://www.zerorpc.io/) is a really nifty library built on top of ZeroMQ. This is probably the easiest way to make call python code from Node.

For a really simple approach and non-robust approach, you could use a tmp file to write the python commands from Node. With an event loop running inside Python, read the tmp file for any changes and execute the commands therein.

Comment: I used before but coudnt make it

Comment: I just want to pick the value where inserted from android

Comment: In that case, you could just write it to a temporary file, and have python read it. Or work with a socket library and pass the value to python.

Comment: You need to try harder. If you were stuck there, you could post that code in a separate question and you might get some help with it.